# MySQL Triggers: INSERT ON log BEFORE DELETE ON table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

this is my first post here! =]

I'm creating a trigger to insert on a log table every time someone tries to delete something from a table

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `user_before_delete`      
BEFORE DELETE ON `user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO log_alert(id, table_id, name)
VALUES('99002', OLD.id, OLD.name);

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '99002'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TRYING TO REMOVE A USER!'
END
```

but the problem is:
the SIGNAL SQLSTATE rollback the whole operation!
So, how do I INSERT on the LOG TABLE and PREVENTE from DELETING the user?

Comment: quick/dirty workaround: change log_alert to be a myisam table. no transactions there, so no way to roll back your insert.

Comment: worked like a charm!!! =D thanks bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc B workaround worked for me  =]

```
quick/dirty workaround: change log_alert to be a myisam table. no transactions there, so no way to roll back your insert. –  Marc B 15 hours ago
```

Just changing the **log_alert** to MyISAM type and the INSERTS wont rollback anymore

Answer (score 0):

Before using `BEGIN/END` Blocks, change the delimiter to `$$`, then switch back:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `user_before_delete`      
BEFORE DELETE ON `user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

INSERT INTO log_alert(id, table_id, name)
VALUES('99002', OLD.id, OLD.name);

SIGNAL SQLSTATE '99002'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'TRYING TO REMOVE A USER!';

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: This is not the problem... What was happened is that my INSERT operations was being rollbacked when calling the SIGNAL SQLSTATE.