# Log the triggers, procedure, function errors in separate Table - printed on the console only

Tags: mysql, error-handling, mariadb

I want to log the errors/exceptions for the triggers, procedures and functions in separate Table.

"my code is look like this":

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SILENCE_DB.GET_WEB_APPLICATION_NAVIGATION(_xxx CHAR(32))
BEGIN
    -- DECLARE THE EXCEPTION AND WORNING HANDLER
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            GET DIAGNOSTICS @_no = NUMBER, @row_no = ROW_COUNT;
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION @_no
            @sql_sat=RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errMsg= MESSAGE_TEXT
            -- to insert the error on my error table 
            CALL INSERT_ERROR_TABLE(........);
            RESIGNAL;
        END;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
            GET DIAGNOSTICS @_no = NUMBER, @row_no = ROW_COUNT;
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION @_no
            @sql_sat=RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @errMsg= MESSAGE_TEXT;
            -- to insert the error on my error table 
            CALL INSERT_ERROR_TABLE(........);
            RESIGNAL;       -- DECLARE THE NOT FOUND HANDLER
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    BEGIN
        -- NOTHING TO DO
    END;
    ................... business code
    ................... business code
    ................... business code
    ................... business code
END;
```

but if I use the **RESIGNAL/SIGNAL** I get the error on console but no insert into the **table ERRORS**, and if I remove the **RESIGNAL/SIGNAL** I did not get the error on the console but the error is inserted on the **ERRORS table** !!!
SO anyone have suggestion how to achieve my target.

Comment: Unclear. WHERE, in what moment, at what code, the error occures?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, but my guess is: you have a trigger, it calls a stored procedure, you want to both signal and log there. For InnoDB, if an error occurs, it undoes the complete query (that triggered the trigger) including anything done to other tables). See e.g. [MySQL Triggers: INSERT ON log BEFORE DELETE ON table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28285859) for a workaround.

Comment: I have change the ERROR Table from to MyISAM type and now it's working fine with me :).thanks MR.Solarflare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as Solarflare said, using the MyISAM instead of InnoDB for the INSERT_ERROR_TABLE type